# Using FileReader inside object

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have an object which has a `loadFile()` method that parses a wav file. I have been using a `FileReader` outside the object and passing `loadFile()` the `ArrayBuffer` from the file read and letting it take over from there. I want to have potentially many of the objects, so I'd like to wrap up a `FileReader` inside the `loadFile()` method so I don't have to deal with all the reader code outside for every object. The problem is, I am not sure how this will work. Here's a code visual:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.property;
    this.anotherProp;
    this.data = new Array(); // array to be filled with PCM data for processing
}

// pass a File object
MyObject.prototype.loadFile = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    reader.onload = function(event) {

        var buffer = event.target.result;

        // do lots of stuff with buffer and eventually fill up this.data[]

    }

}

MyObject.prototype.doProcessing = function() {

    // process this.data[]

}

var file; // a File object I grabbed from somewhere

var myObj = new MyObject();

myObj.loadFile(file);

myObj.doProcessing();
```

What will happen with `loadFile()` here? Will `loadFile` return before I have any data in `myObj.data[]`? Or will it wait for `reader.onload` to fire before returning? If this is the wrong way to do this, how should I do it? Aslo, what if I wanted `loadFile()` to return `false` if something inside `reader.onload` fails?

**Possible Solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/N6vnU/2/

**Current Solution:** I ended up moving the file parsing function out of the object into a web worker, and discovering `FileReaderSync`. Now I send the file off to the web worker and create an object with the results once they return.

Comment: add 'var self=this;' above the reader onload() function, self.data=buffer inside the onload(), and then call self.doProcessing() at the end of reader.onload() and you're golden...

Comment: Thanks, this partially led me to my current solution

Answer (score 0):

Events in Javascript are asynchronous, so you have to assume that `loadFile` will return before `onload` runs (always assume for the worst case, because you cannot predict when an async call will be completed).

Your usual option is adding a callback parameter to `loadFile` which you will call once `onload` is done, or optionally integrating deferreds/futures if that's how you prefer to work.

Also a hint: you need to call `readAsArrayBuffer` **after** you assign the `onload` handler, because again as it is async there's always the chance that you will miss this event if you first instruct the browser to read the file and then attach an event to it.

Comment: I tried adding an onload method to my object. It seems to be working. Let me know if you see a potential problem with it: http://jsfiddle.net/N6vnU/

Comment: well you would usually pass callback functions as a parameter instead of hardcoding them for added flexibility. for example this modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6vnU/3 or using the jQuery definition of promises http://jsfiddle.net/N6vnU/4 -- handling the error state is very simple on both, the solution with promises is a one liner http://jsfiddle.net/N6vnU/5/ and then you need to attach yourself to the `.fail` interface on the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the loadfile will return before the file is actually loaded.
A nice approach could involve the use of promises.

For example, you could use the Q library.
Here's a link to the API: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference

If you already use jQuery, the $.Deferred object could be enough, even though I suggest you to use the promises offered by the Q library.

The MyObject constructor could define a deferred (private would be ideal) to be resolved by the `reader.onload` function.

Knowing so little about the real use of the MyObject instances, consider read the following as pseudo-code.

```
function MyObject() {
    this.def = $.Deferred(); //the deferred to be resolved when the content has been loaded
    this.property;
    this.anotherProp;
    this.data = new Array(); // array to be filled with PCM data for processing
}

// pass a File object
MyObject.prototype.loadFile = function(file) {
    var obj = this,
        reader = new FileReader();
    this.def = $.Deferred();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var buffer = event.target.result;
        obj.def.resolve();
        // do lots of stuff with buffer and eventually fill up this.data[]
    }

}

MyObject.prototype.doProcessing = function() {
    this.def.done(function(){
        // process this.data[]
        console.log('resolved');
    });
}

var file; // a File object I grabbed from somewhere
var x = new MyObject();
x.loadFile(file);
x.doProcessing(); //this would print 'resolved' when the file is loaded
```

Comment: I tried adding an onload method to my object that seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/N6vnU/

Comment: Yes, Robby, that is a nice event-oriented working solution. In a situation like this, the solution is reasonable and easy to understand.
If the desired behavior becomes too complicated, I suggest you to consider the use of promises, because they are a powerful event abstraction.

Comment: Awesome, I will certainly check out promises if things get complex like you said. I appreciate your input!

Comment: Just a heads up Giovanni, this is a bad use of promises. You would actually want to return the promise on the loadFile function and handle what's to be done with the return value externally, ending up with this use case: `x.loadFile(file).then(x.doProcessing)`. Otherwise this code sample is no better than using callbacks and actually more complex.